# ASP.NET Application with MySQL on IIS

Tags: asp.net, mysql, iis

I want to run an ASP.Net app on an ISS-Server (Windows Server 2008).

I have installed the "MySQL-Connector" and the MySQL-DB. I published the ASP.Net app and copied the result into the wwwroot folder.

When i try to run the app, the following errormessage shows up:

```
Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.  

Stack Trace: 


[ArgumentException: Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed.]
   System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(String providerInvariantName) +1402071
   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.GetFactory(String providerString) +34
```

I can't fiqure out why this error is thrown, because i definitely installed the connector.
Should I add something in the Web.Config or somewhere else?

Comment: Can you paste your connection string?

Comment: From the WEB.Config: <add name="DBContext" connectionString="metadata=res://*/MySQL.csdl|res://*/MySQL.ssdl|res://*/MySQL.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=localhost;User Id=*****;database=*****;password=*****&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does your published build contain the connector? Check the bin folder.

Most likely your connector installed to the GAC on the development machine and it is not copied locally to the project, so when you do a build it just builds the site and assumes you've installed it on the server too.

You can manually force it to copy the connector locally by selecting the reference in the Solution Explorer, right clicking and choosing Properties and set Copy Local to true.

Comment: Why should there be a connector in the folder? I installed this one: http://www.mysql.de/products/connector/ It worked for the developement machine, so i installed it on the server too. EDIT: The connector i use was a simple msi file.

Comment: There shouldn't if it's in the GAC of both machines.

Comment: Well... I just reinstalled the Connector on the server... and it works.. Thanks for all your help!!